# how to start graphviz on macosx after installing with home-brew?

Tags: graphviz

```
dave$ brew reinstall graphviz
==> Reinstalling graphviz 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/graphviz-2.40.1_1.high_sier
Already downloaded: /Users/dave/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/2bf5346e72953a60aa26af766451ff7cf1439f4c020c0dc24ee5db10b9795ade--graphviz-2.40.1_1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring graphviz-2.40.1_1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1_1: 500 files, 11.3MB
```

I installed graphviz with homebrew. How do I start it after that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.  Graphviz is a tool not a GUI.

To test it you can do something simple like create a simple graph:

```
digraph "a" {
a -> b
}
```

and then run dot with it.

```
$ dot -Tpng -otest.png test.dot
$ open test.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We also have a Graphviz.app GUI, that is not distributed via Homebrew, or even built in our CI framework on GitLab. I verified last night it still builds and runs and looks ok. The build is extra specially arcane. I'm not sure what to do about this, except it would not be too much trouble to manually package and distribute stable versions on www2.graphviz.org.

I would like to know if Homebrew would take on Graphviz.app (which would mean making the build look more like other GUI programs) but I'm not even sure who to ask.